# "could not find installable isam" exception when trying to read an Excel file with oledb

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, excel-2010, oledbconnection

I'm trying to read an Excel file (xlsx format) using OLEDB.
when trying to open the connection i get the exception "could not find installable isam".

```
string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+fileName+";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;';";
OleDbConnection conn=new OleDbConnection(conStr);
conn.Open();
```

i've researched a lot, mainly here, but all the answers i found didn't solve this issue.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .xlsx, it should be:

```
StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
```

(Note the extra Xml part, the HDR=YES to indicate your file has headers, the IMEX=1 to treat all data as text and the repositioned semi-colon. You would need different connection strings for .xlsm and .xlsb files - see [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/))

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work. i've seen this answer somewhere else already. thanks anyway

Comment: string conStr  = string.Empty;
if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
{
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"; ;
}
else
{
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
}
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
 }
 catch
 {}
}

Comment: It Works For me Does that Works for u?

Comment: it looks exactly the same as my original code, at least the xlsx format, which is the file type i'm using. so i'm not sure what's different about it

Comment: ok, found a wrong spelling of a word, that was the problem now, thanks